# reverse proxy apache to localhost server

Tags: apache, clojure, proxy

I've got a web app running on localhost:3000. I also have an apache server. I would like to reverse proxy the apache server so that requests to /mywebapp get forwarded to the server running on localhost:3000.

I currently have the following config at the bottom of my httpd.conf file, but I'm getting a server error when I try to access it:

```
  ProxyPass /mywebapp http://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse /mywebapp http://localhost:3000
```

Edit - further details:

I'm running a jetty server with java -jar myapp.jar. I'd like to forward requests to an apache server listening on :80 to the jetty server.

I've got mod_proxy_http.so and mod_proxy.so enabled.

I can tell the server is running on localhost - it responds to curl with the appropriate http response. So I'm pretty sure the issue is with my apache setup, but I can't think what the problem would be.

Apache conf file in conf.d for reference: http://pastebin.com/vhXwjbQe

And I've got this in my httpd.conf:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a generic answer because every situation is different so here are some debugging questions to ask yourself:

- if the protocol and port correct on the internal service, http and 3000.
- Is the service actually listening for connections from localhost? is it running in a docker container etc that would require it to be listening on a different interface? You can check for this by looking at the output from mywebapp's logs and see if the request are making it through the proxy.
- Do the paths on the internal service include the prefix that is being passed to Apache or does apache need to strip these off. if for instance mywebapp expects the path "/foo/bar" and apache's reverse proxy is sending it with the context path included "/mywebapp/foo/bar" then it will not match any path in mywebapp.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've added some details above. No requests are making it through the proxy. The server responds with a 404 when I go to mydomain/myapp.